# How to get access to the instance variables from an instatiating class

Tags: python

I have two classes: ClassA and ClassB

ClassA instantiates an instance from ClassB

Is there way to get access inside ClassB to the actual value of the instance variables from ClassA ?

The instance variable could change, so giving it to ClassB as a parameter is not the solution.

```
class ClassA():
    def __init__(self):
        self.var_from_A = 1
        self.b = ClassB()



class ClassB():
    def __init__(self):
        # how to get access to self.var_from_A from ClasseA ?
```

Comment: answer to a coment that was now deleted:
in simple words from ClassB: "i want to get access to the variable from that instance of ClassA that instantiated me"

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding, you want to access `var_from_A` in ClassB. It that's the case, then you can do this. I've passed var_from_A as a parameter to class B. You can make var_from_A as a class variable as well. See the second code for that

```
class ClassA():
    def __init__(self):
        self.var_from_A = 1
        self.b = ClassB(self.var_from_A)



class ClassB():
    def __init__(self, from_a):
        # how to get access to self.var_from_A from ClasseA ?
        print("access elem from A {}".format(from_a))


a = ClassA()
```

making class variable

```
class ClassA():
    var_from_A = 1

    def __init__(self):
        var_from_A = 1
        self.b = ClassB()



class ClassB():
    def __init__(self):
        # how to get access to self.var_from_A from ClasseA ?
        print("access elem from A {}".format(ClassA.var_from_A))


a = ClassA()
```

Comment: The Problem with this solution is that changes to var_from_A don't take place in ClassB. AFAIK Method2 is only allowed with constants.

Answer (score 0):

Now I have the solution on my own: the first class has to give its instance to the second class. So the second class can access every instance-object from the first class:

```
class ClassA():
    def __init__(self):
        self.var_from_A = 1
        self.b = ClassB(self)

    def changing_variable(self):
        self.var_from_A = 2
        self.b.show_variable()
        return

class ClassB():
    def __init__(self, instance_that_instatiated_me):
        self.my_caller = instance_that_instatiated_me
        print("access elem from A {}".format(self.my_caller.var_from_A))

    def show_variable(self):
        print("access elem from A (second time): {}".format(self.my_caller.var_from_A))
        return

a = ClassA()
a.changing_variable()
```